# How to get the path for a file which is inside the src directory in java when compiling with UNIX terminal?

Tags: java, unix, ant

I have the java code

```
    File file = new File(fileName);

    try {

        input = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }



    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(fin);
```

which I am using to read from a text file. However, I am compiling in a UNIX terminal emulator for Windows by using an ANT file and when calling

```
file.getAbsolutePath()
```

it looks for the input file in the  `bin` directory. How can I make it look for the input file in the `src` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `fileName` is a relative path (e.g. `test.txt`, not `/temp/test.txt`), it looks for the file relative to the directory it is currently in. I think you can achieve your goal prepending `../src/` to your `fileName` variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions to this problem:

1. Customize an appropriate ant task to copy the file from the `src` directory to the `bin` directory.
2. Customize an appropriate ant task to package the file into the JAR file and modify your code to load it from inside the JAR file.
3. Put the file in another folder, such as `assets`, and customize an ant task to copy the new folder to the `bin` folder.

Personally, I prefer option 3 because `src` is intended to hold source files. Other assets should be stored separately, in my opinion. Also, if you copy the whole directory, it makes it easier to add additional assets to your project.